# Typescript issue when indexing into a non-Array

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I'm in the process of adapting some javascript into typescript and am encountering difficulty when indexing into certain variables.

Here is the original javascript

```
constructor(input) {
        this.unique = input;
        this.parameters[key] = Parameter.makeParam(this.unique[key], oldParam);
    }
```

The input and unique are boolean values which describes whether or not the instance is unique. The associated key is a string, and unique[key] should also be a string.

Assigning the type as `unique: boolean`
functions for `this.unique = input` but not for `this.unique[key]`. However, if I instead use
`unique: {[index: string]: string}`
it will function for `this.unique[key]` but not `this.unique = input`.

Is there a way to maintain unique as it is used in the original javascript, or do I need to split it into multiple variables? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You *could* type `key` as `keyof boolean`, however if `this.unique` is a boolean, then `this.unique[key]` makes very little sense. What exactly are you trying to get from a boolean?

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link to code)](https://tsplay.dev/w26Arw), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.